# Proper way to insert and retrieve date in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm adding date from user input to MySQL database which is working fine but still want to know is this the proper way of doing this?

**This is my table structure:**

```
--------------------------
| COLUMNS    | DATATYPE  |
--------------------------
| birth_id   | int(4) PK |
| birth_date | date      |
--------------------------
```

**And here is how I'm doing it:**

```
// Getting user input date
$date = $_POST[‘birth_date’];

// Format the date from user input to YYYY-MM-DD
// it seems like mysql date datatype supports only
// this format… Also I have to convert the string 
// to time in order to change the date format :/
$format_date = date( ‘Y-m-d’, strtotime($date) );


// My query
$my_qry = “INSERT INTO birthdays SET birth_date = ‘$format_date’“;


// Execute query…
```

The above code added the date into `birth_date` column of the table with this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

---

**Now I have to retrieve the date and display it in different format.**

```
// Execute query to get the data and the result stored in an object $obj

echo date(‘d-m-Y’, strtotime( $obj->birth_date ));
```

The above code gave me result in the exact format that I wanted `DD-MM-YYYY`

So as I asked earlier that is this the only way or are there any more and professional ways to achieve this?

Comment: Only way, MYSQL expects a date to be a the specific format `YYYY-MM-DD` that way is always knows how to deal with it properly (sort etc) it is up to us developers (in the presentation layer) to manipluate for our users who want to see it in the miriad of different formats that exist around the world

Comment: You might want to be careful with those single and double quotes you appear to be using! Are you using Word as an editor? Use a text editor, maybe NOTEPAD++ for example

Comment: I use PHP Storm... SO you are saying that My way is appropriate?

Comment: Also what do you mean by that I should be careful with single and double quotes. Am I using it wrongly?

Comment: They are not showing as standard ascii quotes, That normally means someone is using a document editor and not a simple text editor

Comment: Oh Sorry about that... I wrote that code in word before pasting it here... But in my code editor all quotes are good :)

Comment: i think this one way to make CRUD operation on your application. But I would suggest to use stored procedures instead of directly putting your queries on the code itself to prevent injections.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `strtotime();` method?

Comment: Define 'wanna'.

Comment: Wanna = Want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo (new \DateTime($obj->birth_date))->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: Why is there a slash after new?

Comment: Because DateTime object have a global namespace

Comment: it shows me the date like this: `2525-1010-20162016`... I this is the correction it need `echo (new \DateTime($obj->birth_date))->format('d-m-Y');`

Comment: I have also tried it without the slash \ and it work fine... Is it necessary to add the slash?